# why dropzone submits form twice

Tags: spring-mvc, dropzone.js

Hi I am trying to integrate my form with some other fields and dropzone I find that the controller is called twice not sure why.
Could anyone please help me

```
autoProcessQueue : false,
    uploadMultiple : true,
    maxFilesize : 256, // MB
    parallelUploads : 10,
    maxFiles : 10,
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    previewsContainer : ".dropzone-previews",



    //The setting up of the dropzone
    init : function() {

        var myDropzone = this;

        // first set autoProcessQueue = false
        $("form").one("submit", function(event) {
              myDropzone.processQueue();  



        });
```

thanks
priya

Comment: Try to add ```event.preventDefault();``` before ```myDropzone.processQueue();```

Answer (score 1):

stop form submit until dropzone upload and after that you have to upload form.

```
var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (file) {

        if (myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length > 0) {
            if (submitfiles === true) {
                submitfiles = false;
                return;
            }

            file.preventDefault();
            myDropzone.processQueue();

            myDropzone.on("complete", function () {
                submitfiles = true;
                $('#submit').trigger('click');
            });
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with the following code in the `init` function:

```
init: function() {
      dz = this;
            document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function handler(e) {
                if (dz.getAcceptedFiles().length > 0) {
                    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, handler);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    dz.processQueue();
                }
          });
            this.on("queuecomplete", function(file) {
                document.getElementById("submit").click();
            });

  },
  autoProcessQueue: false,
```